# Google API OAuth2 access with Access and Refresh Tokens .net

Tags: vb.net, api

I am trying to figure out how to get permanent access to a users Google Calendar with OAuth2.   I am at the point that I can get the user to authorize access and I have the AccessToken, RefreshToken, and/or the complete Response Token from Google stored in a database.

The issue I am facing is how to get these tokens in to a credential in the Google API.  I have found no examples that work.  I have tried a few things.   It may be as simple as I am missing a reference to a dll that I cannot figure out.  The GoogleCredential.Builder() seems to be the way to go, but I cannot find it anywhere except for the Java API.

Here is the closest I have gotten.  The issue is how to create the correct credentials.

```
  Dim user As CRMUser = GetUser(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)

        Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)


        Dim ClientID As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleCalendarApplicationClientID").ToString()
        Dim ClientSecret As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GoogleCalendarApplicationClientSecret").ToString()
        Dim service As CalendarService

        Dim credential As GoogleCredential = New GoogleCredential.Builder().setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(httpTransport).setClientSecrets(ClientID, ClientSecret).build()
        credential.setAccessToken(user.GoogleUserToken)
        credential.setRefreshToken(user.GoogleRefreshToken)


        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "VB.NET Calendar Sample"
        service = New CalendarService(initializer)
```

Comment: [Don't post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225698/is-it-correct-to-post-whole-of-the-code-in-question) whole code in your question.